# Using the isset function in php I want to display a confirmation message but its not showing properly

Tags: php, html, forms

Basically I created a leapyear calculator, but to improve user experience i want it to display a message on the webpage confirming whether or not the year entered is a leapyear without changing the webpage.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Web,programming" />
<title>Leap year form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$year = isset($_GET["leapyear"]);
function is_leapyear($year){

    if(is_numeric($year)){
        if($year%4 ==0)
            if($year%100 ==0)
                if($year%400 ==0){
                    return true;
                }
        return false;
    }
}
if (isset($_GET["confirm"])){
    if ($year == true){
        echo'<span style="color:#008631;">';
        echo"$year is a leap year</span>";
    }else{
        echo'<span style="color:#FF0000;">';
        echo "$year is not a leap year</span>";
    }
}
?>
<h1>Lab 03 Task 2 - Leap Year</h1> 
<form action = "leapyear_selfcall.php" method = "get" >
    <label for="leapyear">Enter a year</label>
    <input type="text" name="leapyear"/>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Check For Leap Year"/>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I get is "1 is a leapyear" and not the entered input. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Hello, remember to indent your code for more lisibility, it will help you a lot in the future !

Comment: `$year = isset($_GET["leapyear"]);` Remember `isset()` returns a boolean TRUE or FALSE and not the value in the array you are testing

Comment: `is_leapyear($year)` is a function, you dont appear to call it ever!

Comment: @RiggsFolly So i should put a code like this `if (isset($_GET["confirm"])==true)`and
`if (is_leapyear($year))`?

Comment: No, you are not loading the `$year` variable with the content of `$_GET["leapyear"]` when you use `$year = isset($_GET["leapyear"]);` that is loading True or False into `$year` and true is being assumed to be 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok I see so i must it in a way that that true is equal to the year that was input into the form?

Comment: no `if ( isset($_GET["leapyear"]) ) { $year = $_GET["leapyear"] } }else{ error message} }`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I see ok let me try it out

Comment: @RiggsFolly I entered the code you commented but it is now reading my first `echo` statement as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made a mistake in the year checking condition. Please see below updated code:

```
$year = isset($_GET["leapyear"]) ? $_GET["leapyear"] : 0 ;
```

Added above line to set year value in $year if set otherwise zero

```
if (isset($_GET["confirm"])){
if (is_leapyear($year)){
            echo'<span style="color:#008631;">';
            echo"$year is a leap year</span>";
            }
else
 {
            echo'<span style="color:#FF0000;">';
            echo "$year is not a leap year</span>";
   }
}
```

Comment: I added the updated code but now its reading "1 is not a leap year" regardless of the year I input

Comment: Which year you have entered for testing?

Comment: 2020 and 2021 where the two I entered

Comment: Because you have assigned isset value in Year variable. Isset return 1/0 . I am updating my answer please check

Comment: Ok now the input is fixed, now it is a matter of getting the logic correct because it is returning "is not a leap year"

Comment: Please understand the logic and whatever you have written and also debug the code step by step for a better idea and bug resolution. Anyway if your problem is resolved then accept the answer and upvote